# Why does AspNetCore SelectList selectedValue parameter not work?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I am able to build up my Select List and render it in a Select taghelper in a view.
But I am unable to set the default selection.

I build up my ViewModel and SelectList here in an AdminAccountController:

```
    public PartialViewResult CreateUser()
    {
        SelectList rolesList = new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles, "User");
        return PartialView("_CreateUser", new CreateUserViewModel
        {
            RolesList = rolesList
        });
    }
```

CreateUserViewModel looks like this:

```
public class CreateUserViewModel
{
    public string NameSource { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; } = "Password";

    public IdentityRole Role { get; set; }

    public SelectList RolesList { get; set; }
}
```

The RoleManager is coming from constructor.
And my view consumes the SelectList here:

```
    <select asp-for="Role.Name" asp-items="Model.RolesList"
        class="form form-control">
    </select>
```

With this line in the controller PartialViewResult CreateUser()
action:

```
SelectList rolesList = new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles, "User");
```

Shouldn't the second parameter, "User", set the default select option to ..."User"?

It has no effect.  How can I set this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
SelectList rolesList =
            new SelectList(_roleManager.Roles.OrderBy(r => r.Name), _roleManager.Roles.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Name == "User"));
```